# Humorous absurdity while spelling out

Tags: spelling

In my country (Italy) city names are generally used when spelling, for example: "R di Roma" which literally means "R as in Roma". Sometimes it is considered nonsense to use as an example a word that does not contain the letter indicated, for example: "U as in Milano".
When translating the nonsense into English, could a literal translation (C as in London) be fine or is there a more adequate form?

Comment: Hmmm . . . not sure that would translate well, because in English speaking countries we tend to use the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet), A for Alpha, B for Bravo, C for Charlie, D for Delta, E for Echo, F for Foxtrot, L for Lima, R for Romeo, etc.

Comment: It sounds to me the Italian equivalent of [Clapham and Dwyer;s *Cockney Alphabet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney_Alphabet#:~:text=In%201936%2C%20the%20comedy%20double,'th%20highlanders%20(Seaforth%20Highlanders)). It begins: A for 'orses (hay for horses)
B for mutton (beef or mutton)
C for 'th highlanders (Seaforth Highlanders)
D for 'ential (deferential)
E for Adam (Eve or Adam)
F for 'vescence (effervescence)
G for police (chief of police)
H for respect (age for respect)... for the remainder click on the link.

Comment: @BillyKerr, in my experience (in the US) people who know that alphabet will just use it directly: "My name is spelled bravo oscar bravo". People who don't know it typically use certain common names and words: "B as in boy" or "N as in Nancy", etc.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know the NATO alphabet well enough to use it instinctively, so I would be more likely to think up my own words on the spot.

Comment: Can you explain the joke? Why is it funny? Is it just meaningless, or is there some connection of U with Milano? Is it just something that's funny because it's an in-joke or a tradition or reference to some book or TV show which did this, in which case you probably can't translate?

Comment: I'm also reminded of some "sadistic phonetic alphabets" I've seen, like *A for aegis, B for bdellium, C for chthonic*, etc., where the joke is that the *letters* are technically correct, the *sounds* are extremely confusing, since they're pronounced EE-jis, DELL-ee-um, TAH-nik, etc.

Comment: @stangdon - that could work here I think.  E is for eye. P is for Pneumonia. X is for Xanadu. LOL;)

Comment: @StuartF the joke is that Milano doesn't start with the letter U, and more importantly it doesn't contain that letter at all

Comment: thank you very much everyone

Comment: @BillyKerr I hope you remind non-native English speakers that as far as pneumonia is concerned "the P is silent - as in psausages".

Comment: I chose note to CV in the CV queue, but I'm pretty skeptical about how this is useful for learning the English language. (It seems to be more of an issue for translators, not learners.)

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with jokes, especially jokes in which you pretend to make a mistake: How is the native speaker supposed to know which mistakes are real and which are jokes?

So when you say, in Italian, "U as in Milano", there is a shared understanding — of course it is clear that *Milano* doesn't start with a "U", so this is funny.

But when a native speaker of English is talking with a non-native speaker, we are ready to forgive mistakes.  We actively allow you to get things wrong! We know that speaking in a foreign language is hard and mistakes are okay.  So if you say "U as in Milan", we might not recognise this as a "joke".

So, jokes are hard.

But this particular joke doesn't seem very funny.  Why would you want to make this joke?? If you are spelling out a word, why do you need to make a nonsense spelling?

As noted in the comment, there is a set of words for spelling "Alfa, Bravo, Charlie.." Or it is very common to use personal names "F as in Freddy".  I can think of no situation in which a native speaker has taken this as an opportunity for "nonsense" with me.

Comment: I can think of no situation in which a native speaker has taken this as an opportunity for "nonsense".  --- But WS2 has provided with an example

Comment: The aim is to give a funny title to information intended for Italian and foreign people, therefore the title must be reported in Italian and English.
Even in Italy names other than cities are sometimes used, therefore, assuming that the information is about me, the title could be in Italian "Z di Pippo"; if for the English version alongside you write "Z as in Pippo" would it make sense as a joke or would it be incomprehensible?

Comment: My anwer stands.  Because you are not a native speaker, I will allow you to make mistakes.  So making mistakes on purpose to be funny won't work.

Comment: I've been living in Italy for almost 40 years and this is the first time I've heard of this play on words. Of course one could forget that it's "P come Palermo", and instead say "P come *pipi*" (pee/wee) but as a joke among friends. *That* could be funny…

Comment: @Pippo It would come off as an odd mistake first, and maybe some people would think about it and go, "Did they mean this as a joke?" That's as close as you would get.

Comment: Perhaps people might make a joke about English spelling  "P as in Psychology" or "F as in Cough"

Comment: Thanks everyone, this has deviated a bit from the original question but now I have enough information